# Is the isotropy subset $X_H$ an open and dense subset of the fixed point set $X^H$?

Tags: general-topology, finite-groups, representation-theory, group-actions

Assume that $G$ is a finite group acting by automorphisms on a topological space $X$ (For concreteness, assume that $X$ is a complex manifold). Let $H$ be a parabolic subgroup of $G$. Denote by $X_H$ the isotropy subset of elements $x$ in $X$ with stabilizer $Stab(x)=H$ and let $X^H$ be the set of $H$-fixed points in $X$. The isotropy subset $X_H$ is a subset in $X^H$. Is it true that $X_H$ is open and dense in $X^H$?

On page 20 of the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0212279.pdf it is stated that in the case when $X$ is a (symplectic) vector space, $X_H$ is Zariski-open, hence dense in $X^H$. Does anyone know a proof of that statement and more importantly if it generalizes to arbitary topological spaces $X$ with a finite group action.

Comment: If $H$ is trivial and for each $x\in X$ there is a nontrivial $g\in G$ such that $gx=x$, then $X_H$ is the empty set while $X^H=X$, right? So I'm not sure about being open, but definitely does not have to be dense.

Comment: @freakish If $H$ is trivial and $G$ acts freely on $X$, then all points have trivial stabilizers. Hence, $X_H=X$ and $X^H=X$.

Comment: Yes, yes, that was my mistake. I've change "freely" to "each $x$ is fixed by a non-trivial group element". In particular this covers all topological spaces with all non-trivial groups acting trivially $(g,x)\mapsto x$.

Comment: The situation that you describe cannot arise. There is always a so-called principal stratum of points whose stabilizer is trivial. Moreover, in that case, the isotropy set is always dense and open. The question if this remains true for nontrivial subgroups $H$ of $G$.

Comment: I don't see anything in your question preventing this from happening. I mean the first question. I didn't of course read the paper you linked. If there are any additional assumptions you need, then please add them to the question itself.

Comment: Maybe I should specify that the subgroup $H$ is parabolic, meaning that it is by default a non-trivial stabilizer of a given element $x$ in $X$. What I said is true. This follows from the theory of statification of spaces by orbit types. There is always a principal stratum which is dense and open in the whole space. When the group is finite, the principal stratum is the isotropy set of the trivial group.